# How to clear items in DevExpress LookupEdit

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress, repositorylookupedit

Hai,
  Am using DevExpress LookupEdit in C#.NET application.I want to clear all items in the LookupEdit.Please help

code:

```
lkpLabItem.Properties.DataSource = null; 
         lkpLabItem .Properties.DataSource = _lab.selectChemicals ();
         lkpLabItem.Properties.DisplayMember = "labitem_Name";
         lkpLabItem.Properties.ValueMember = "labItem_ID";
         lkpLabItem.Properties.BestFitMode = BestFitMode.BestFit;
         lkpLabItem.Properties.SearchMode = SearchMode.AutoComplete;

         lkpLabItem.Properties.Columns.Add(new LookUpColumnInfo("labitem_Name", 100, "Lab Items"));
         lkpLabItem.Properties.AutoSearchColumnIndex = 1;
```

Thank you.[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got items correctly.

problem is that am creating `LookUpColumnInfo whenever am calling same method.
code:

```
lkpLabItem.Properties.DataSource = null; 
         lkpLabItem .Properties.DataSource = _lab.selectChemicals ();
         lkpLabItem.Properties.DisplayMember = "labitem_Name";
         lkpLabItem.Properties.ValueMember = "labItem_ID";
         lkpLabItem.Properties.BestFitMode = BestFitMode.BestFit;
         lkpLabItem.Properties.SearchMode = SearchMode.AutoComplete;
```

create  `LookUpColumnInfo` only first time then call method without `LookUpColumnInfo`

Answer (score 2):

LookupEdit is mean to provide list of data from the linked datasource, so, to clear the items you can set its DataSource property to null:

```
lookUpEdit1.Properties.DataSource = null;
```

or, if you are using a BindingSource as the LookupEdit data source, you can set its DataSource property to null.

Comment: i have given what you specified above but its not clearing the values and items showing 2 times . I given code  above

Comment: In the code above, you are re-bindng the list of the editor to _lab.selectChemicals (), so you get values from selectChemicals () in the list. This is not what you expect to happens?

Comment: am calling above method when insert new value.So it bind the new value to LookupEdit.But it show same item  as 2 section

Comment: I'm not sure if I've understood: user types "Reference1" in the edit portion, then click on "+" to add "Reference1" to hte linked table?